# Counting the frequency of words in a pandas column and counting another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a data frame with comments and their labels.

| Comments | Label |
| --- | --- |
| I love my Teammates | Positive |
| We need higher pay | Suggestions |
| I hate my boss | Negative |

I would like to get an output like

| Word | count | Positive | Negative | Suggestions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| my | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Teammates | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| love | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| We | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| need | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| higher | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| pay | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| hate | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| boss | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

I was able to get the word count by using

```
df.Comments.str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts()
```

But I am not able to get the label counts. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
out = (
    df['Comments'].str.split().explode().to_frame('Word').join(df['Label']).assign(value=1) \
                  .pivot_table('value', 'Word', 'Label', aggfunc='count', fill_value=0) \
                  .assign(Count=lambda x: x.sum(axis=1))
)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
Label      Negative  Positive  Suggestions  Count
Word                                             
I                 1         1            0      2
Teammates         0         1            0      1
We                0         0            1      1
boss              1         0            0      1
hate              1         0            0      1
higher            0         0            1      1
love              0         1            0      1
my                1         1            0      2
need              0         0            1      1
pay               0         0            1      1
```

Details:

**Step 1.** explode each comment into word and assign a dummy value.

```
out = df['Comments'].str.split().explode().to_frame('Word').join(df['Label']).assign(value=1)
print(out)

# Output:
        Word        Label  value
0          I     Positive      1
0       love     Positive      1
0         my     Positive      1
0  Teammates     Positive      1
1         We  Suggestions      1
1       need  Suggestions      1
1     higher  Suggestions      1
1        pay  Suggestions      1
2          I     Negative      1
2       hate     Negative      1
2         my     Negative      1
2       boss     Negative      1
```

**Step 2.** pivot your dataframe.

```
out = out.pivot_table('value', 'Word', 'Label', aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)
print(out)

# Output:
Label      Negative  Positive  Suggestions
Word                                      
I                 1         1            0
Teammates         0         1            0
We                0         0            1
boss              1         0            0
hate              1         0            0
higher            0         0            1
love              0         1            0
my                1         1            0
need              0         0            1
pay               0         0            1
```

**Step 3.**: create the `count` column.

```
out = out.assign(Count=lambda x: x.sum(axis=1))
print(out)

# Output:
Label      Negative  Positive  Suggestions  Count
Word                                             
I                 1         1            0      2
Teammates         0         1            0      1
We                0         0            1      1
boss              1         0            0      1
hate              1         0            0      1
higher            0         0            1      1
love              0         1            0      1
my                1         1            0      2
need              0         0            1      1
pay               0         0            1      1
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes it does, Is there a way I can add the original comment associated with each word in a separate column?

Comment: How do I merge the original dataframe with the derived dataframe? I need the comments along with the word and count?

Comment: For the words `I` and `my`, there are 2 comments that contain this words. Explain me how do you want to set the new column? Join comments by `', '` or create a list of comments?

Comment: Thank you Corralien! I found a work around by using Power BI directly to achieve this,

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following

```
out = (
    df.assign(Word=lambda df: df.Comments.str.split())   # Create a column 'World' with the list of words 
      .explode('Word')  # explode the list of words into new rows 
      .pipe(lambda df: pd.crosstab(df.Word, df.Label)) # cross table/ pivot table between 'Word' and 'Label' columns
      .assign(Count=lambda df: df.sum(axis=1))   # Count the column's total
      .reset_index()  # 'Word' index to column
      .rename_axis(columns=None) # remove the name ('Label') of the columns axis
)
```

Output:

```
>>> out 

        Word  Negative  Positive  Suggestions  Count
0          I         1         1            0      2
1  Teammates         0         1            0      1
2         We         0         0            1      1
3       boss         1         0            0      1
4       hate         1         0            0      1
5     higher         0         0            1      1
6       love         0         1            0      1
7         my         1         1            0      2
8       need         0         0            1      1
9        pay         0         0            1      1
```

Comment: Clean and Self explanatory!

Comment: @YanniTheDeveloper Thanks ;)

Comment: Thank you guys!